# C# Fallback Value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In javascript you can use the `||` operator to essentially have a fallback value, so if the preceding statements return a falsey value, then the value after the `||` is used.

So, for example here if `GetComponent` returns null, then we default to `Vector2.zero`

```
Vector3 velocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity || Vector2.zero;
```

Is there a shorthand way of writing this? Because with the above I get:

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector2' and 'Vector2'

Comment: The coalesce operator in C# is `??` (as in `var x = a ?? b;`), but it only works for reference types.

Comment: I am getting the same error... `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector2' and 'Vector2'`

Comment: Sounds like they're not reference types.

Comment: Indeed. `VectorX` are structs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C#4,

```
Vector3 velocity;
var comp = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

if (comp != null)
    velocity = comp.velocity;
else
    velocity = Vector2.zero;
```

Comment: I think you mean `if (comp != null)` in the first example.

Comment: Looks like the ternary operator, is the way I will have to go with C# 4 (in this circumstance). However, it is good to know that the `??` does exist!

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can use:

```
Vector3 velocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()?.velocity ?? Vector2.zero;
```

The `?.` operator ensures that if `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` return `null` then the `.velocity` is not resolved and the whole statement is null.

Next, the `??` operator returns value on the left (`GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()?.velocity`) if it is not `null` and if the value on the left side is `null` then it returns value on the right side (`Velocity2.zero`).

Comment: To be a pedant, I think you mean `?.`

Comment: This does't work in unity `Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 4. Please use language version 6 or greater.`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn You may be able to use C# 6 in Unity. See [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/7tqz0z/current_c_version/).

Comment: @charliefox2, you are right, thank you. Programming is all about details :).